# Rails Unicorn - Delay between starting request and reaching controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicorn

I am using Unicorn as my app server for my Rails app, and am trying to figure out why there sometimes is sometimes a non-trivial (> 5 seconds) delay between the start of a request, and when it reaches my controller.

This is what my production.log prints out:

```
Started GET "/search/articles.json?q=mashable.com" for 138.7.7.33 at 2015-07-23 14:59:19 -0400**
  Parameters: {"q"=>"mashable.com"}

Searching articles for keyword: mashable.com, format: json, Time: 2015-07-23 14:59:26 -0400
```

Notice how there is a 7 second delay in between STARTED GET: and "Searching articles for keyword", which is the first thing the controller method does.

articles.json is routed to my controller method "articles" which simply does this for now:

```
def articles
        format = params[:format]
        keyword = params["q"]

        Rails.logger.info "Searching articles for keyword: #{keyword}, format: #{format}, Time: #{Time.now.to_s}"

end
```

This is my routes.rb

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    match '/search/articles' => 'search#articles' 
    #more routes here, but articles is the first route
end
```

What could possibly cause this delay? Is it because an Unicorn worker is busy? Is it because an Unicorn worker is taking up too much memory which leads the system to be slow?

Note: I don't believe the delay is in making any database connections but I could be wrong. The code doesn't need to make a database call, and the max connections for my database is 1000, and there are usually at most 1-2 connections.

Comment: could be a myriad of reasons - you'll need to monitor your system resources as well as unicorn. If nothing is in place, adding a newrelic agent might be the quickest/easiest option

Comment: Is this happening with Puma, Passenger etc as well?

Comment: What does the last line of the GET request say, ie the one that sais `Completed 200 OK in 100ms (Views: 50.0ms | ActiveRecord: 50.0ms)`

Comment: Have you attempted to use a different app server to see if it's just unicorn?

Comment: In what environment is this app running, with as many particulars as you can share?  Is the Rails environment production or development?  Is it in the cloud?  Whose and what are the specs of the virtual server?  In other words, what is the environment?  Also, what have you done to try to monitor or resolve the problem?  When the delay occurs, what has happened immediately before that?  Have you pushed new code so that the server is preprocessing assets, for example?  Thank you...

Comment: Network delay? Could it be that your clients need 10 seconds to finish sending request to the server?

Answer (score 12):

Three thoughts:

1. You'll probably be better served using Puma instead of Unicorn
2. It could be that your system is running out of memory, or it could have plenty of memory available: install New Relic to troubleshoot where the bottleneck is
3. It could also be that you have more Unicorn instances than the number of connections your DB allows, in which case the instance is having to wait for others to disconnect before it can connect. This would likely manifest itself with irregular 5-second delays rather than happening every time.

Comment: But there are no database connections being made in between "STARTED GET" and the first log statement being printed. No meaningful work occurs.

Comment: Actually ActiveRecord (and thus Rails) manages this automatically, and only spools up a DB connection upon the first SQL query, which is exactly when you seem to be experiencing the problem.  More on that here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections#connection-pool.  Because you're using Unicorn, you have many instances running, and if this # is larger than the # of connections the DB will allow, then a disconnected process will have to wait for others to disconnect once it has submitted its first SQL query.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it might be caused by an before_filter callback, you should check it

Answer (score 4):

I think it can be because of lack of memory and thus frequent garbage collection, which freeze whole system.

Comment: Unicorn uses just 15% of total memory, so I doubt that's it

Answer (score 3):

If it's a production problem it could be caused by slow clients sending requests. New Relic and Monit are good options. You could consider sending signals to Unicorn workers to restart them to better understand the problem.

You could also try adding `preload_app true` in your Unicorn config to speed up the startup time of worker processes.

Comment: How can slow clients cause this problem?

Comment: Some good information here: http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/if-unix-is-good-for-unicorn-why-cant-unicorn-handle-slow-connections